# how to access the grid control name inside the datatemplate in code behind c#

Tags: c#, wpf

how to access the control inside the Popup. popup is accessable but why i cant access datagrid inside the popup.how can we access all child control inside a  DataTemplate

```
 <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="193" CanUserAddRows="False" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560"
              CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding" >
        <!--Resources Start-->
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_GotFocus" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <!--Resources End-->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Ledger Head Start-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ledger Head" Width="200" >

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LedgerHead}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding LedgerHead}" Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"  KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" />
                            <Popup x:Name="popup1"  AllowsTransparency="True"  PopupAnimation="Slide" Width="500" Height="800"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textPopUp}" >
                                <Grid>
                                    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid2"></DataGrid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: The problem is not the grid but the datatemplate. Why you must do that?

Comment: You should get popup1.Child and use VisualTreeHelper to findChild. you can get my code from https://github.com/Ilya-Grigoryan/SynchDataGridScroll.git and see the VisualTreeHelperEx.cs, with this extension you can find any child that you want to.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312441/i-cannot-get-the-selection-box-in-my-xbox-uwp-app-popup/52316289#52316289

Comment: auto complete a combobox or textbox in datagrid cell .

Comment: what i am trying to do is show in the above code.But i can not access datagrid2 in the pop up.We can access popup1 but we are not able to access datagrid2 because that child control not accessable inside popup 1.

Answer (score 0):

No, We can not access controls inside a data template using its names.
but,

1. to assign data source to the grid view, you can do it in the
   **loaded** event of grid by type casting sender to gridview.
2. to get the selected data of grid, you can use the **selectionchanged** event of
   grid by type casting sender to gridviewitem.

Comment: we are using datagrid in wpf